Since Ubuntu 22.04, 24.04 printing not detecting correct paper size based on pdf size
printing on Ubuntu 22.04, 24.04 no longer automatically detects correct paper size based on pdf size (Using system dialog). Printing on Ubuntu 20.04 and older versions would just stretch page across, without changing paper size. I have custom paper size, and when i print pdf thats eg. A4 size, it would just print A4 independent of the actual size of paper in printer. I tried changing drivers, downgrading cups packages to older versions:
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y libcups2=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-daemon=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-client=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-core-drivers=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-filters=1.27.4-1ubuntu0.2
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-filters-core-drivers=1.27.4-1ubuntu0.2

I added focal repos and installed specific versions.
Is there a specific package that i should maybe downgrade, or some other settings.
I also tried configurations from Ubuntu 20.04, printer ppds etc.

Thanks, i also tried every minor version so i just put major version in.

Have you tried Settings > Printers select the printer you are using and click on the wheel icon. Select Printing Options and then the media size from the drop down. Add that to your question.

Ubuntu does not have "major" and "minor" versions. The version numbers represent calendar dates of releases: 22.04 = 2022 April. There are two releases every year (Example: 22.04 and 22.10), which is why the correct release terminology is important.

@graham I don't have issue with selecting paper size or setting the size. Printing from google chrome with system dialog used to scale up printing depending on pdf size, now it doesn't. I can't find any setting, unfortunately, that will fix this.

so basically you are saying this is not an Ubuntu issue but a Google Chrome issue. Raise a support ticket with them. I use FF and that references the printers from within the Ubuntu framework.

@graham Browser is irrelevant, same thing happens on FF. I tried multiple versions of google chrome also, nothing changes. Only thing that i see are different CUPS versions.

I finally managed to properly downgrade cups and hp drivers.
Posting here for reference.
Take /etc/apt/sources.list from Ubuntu 20.04.
Make backup of existing one:
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
Copy /etc/apt/sources.list from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.
Remove Cups.
sudo apt remove --purge cups*
Reboot
Install specific version of cups and drivers.
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y libcups2=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-daemon=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-client=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-core-drivers=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups=2.3.1-9ubuntu1
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-filters=1.27.4-1ubuntu0.2
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y cups-filters-core-drivers=1.27.4-1ubuntu0.2
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades -y printer-driver-postscript-hp=3.20.3+dfsg0-2

Hold downgraded packages.
sudo apt-mark hold cups* hpijs* libcups2 printer-driver-postscript-hp* printer-driver-hpijs*

I don't like this solution, until i find the reason why this stopped working, or if someone can point me into right direction I am calling quits...
Return the original /etc/apt/sources.list from backup.
So to reiterate, in new versions of Cups (filters, drivers etc...) printing pdf from system dialog without specifying paper size will rescale printed image to the size of selected paper (eg. A5).
Older version would just print original pdf size (eg. A4).
This happens on multiple Debian based distributions (Ubuntu, Mint).\
UPDATE
This is cups-filters issue, not 100% why exactly.
I opted out to manually downgrade only cups-filters, cups-filters-core-drivers and install libqpdf26 (requirement for cups-filters) from Ubuntu 20.04 repos since i can't find the way to set scaling.
Marked those packages on hold:
sudo apt-mark hold cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers libqpdf26


You copied a file for Ubuntu Core 20?

@DavidDE I just took sources.list from Ubuntu 20.04 ( just lazy ) so i can downgrade packages. I advise against this, since you can leave your Ubuntu 22.04 installation with broken packages.
